# Drupal: How to use Taxonomy to implement my idea

Tags: php, drupal-6, tags, taxonomy

I have a bunch of Bout nodes. Each Bout is associated with a school, and a player who goes to that school. I am thinking it will work to do this association through taxonomy. (The schools and players are drawn from a list that remains fairly constant over time.)

One idea is to have the school name be the parent term, with players as children terms:

```
Princeton University
    Jorma
    Akiva
    Andy
```

Would this work, in terms of enforcing integrity constraints? (Each bout must be associated with one school and one player.) Or am I better off using a different taxonomy structure? Different vocabs? (But I want to maintain a way the connection between players and schools. Given a school, I want to be able to retrieve the corresponding players.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make nodes and players into nodes, and use (required) node reference CCK fields to bind them all together. The [Node Referrer module](http://drupal.org/project/nodereferrer) allows you to use those node references in a two-way manner as you seem to want to do.

Comment: I'd rather use the taxonomy system. You really think nodes would be that much better?

Comment: I do, yes. It's a lot more flexible, and it allows you to easily eventually add features to the node pages - player profiles, school photos, etc.